# MSSQL 2 столбца из одной таблицы по разным условиям

Tags: sql-server

Структура исходной таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RW_ReceivedData] (
    [Ident] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DeviceId] int NOT NULL,
    [ClassId] smallint NOT NULL,
    [LogicalName] binary(6) NOT NULL,
    [AttId] tinyint NOT NULL,
    [Time] datetime NOT NULL,
    [ReceivedTime] datetime NOT NULL,
    [Value] bigint NULL,
    [Event] tinyint NULL,
    [Unit] tinyint NOT NULL,
    [Scaler] tinyint NOT NULL,
    [NormValue] numeric(38,19) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

)

Поле исходной таблицы

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RW_ReceivedData] ([Ident], [DeviceId], [ClassId], [LogicalName], [AttId], [Time], [ReceivedTime], [Value], [Event], [Unit], [Scaler], [NormValue]) VALUES ('908', '1', '4', CAST(0x01000f0800ff AS varbinary(8000)), '2', '2012-10-07 00:00:00.0', '2012-10-07 01:35:24.863', '1951', '1', '30', '1', '19510.0000000000000000000');
```

Нужно получить несколько столбцов с значением [Value] в зависимости от бинарника [LogicalName]

По 1 параметру я получаю так:

```
SELECT TOP 10 dbo.RW_ReceivedData.[Value] AS Value1
FROM RW_ReceivedData
WHERE dbo.RW_ReceivedData.LogicalName = CAST(0x01000F0800FF AS varbinary(8000))
```

Но как получить сразу несколько?

Comment: Охренеть. Структуру таблицы RW_ReceiveData и желаемый результат -- в студию. (Я вижу названия полей Value1 и Value2 и какую-то табличку со столбцами param1 и param2. Между ними есть какая-нибудь связь или это просто "рыбу заворачивали"?)

Comment: Отредактировал топик

Comment: Я знаю как развернуть обычную таблицу,  но как раввернуть таблицу с бинарниками?

    SELECT  [CAST(0x01000F0800FF AS varbinary(8000))] AS param1
            ,[CAST(0x01000F0801FF AS varbinary(8000))] AS param2  
    FROM    (      
        SELECT  *
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.RW_ReceivedData.LogicalName ORDER BY dbo.RW_ReceivedData.LogicalName) n      
        FROM    RW_ReceivedData) t  
    PIVOT   (      
        MIN(value) FOR dbo.RW_ReceivedData.LogicalName IN ([CAST(0x01000F0800FF AS varbinary(8000))],[CAST(0x01000F0800FF AS varbinary(8001))])  
    ) pvt

Comment: Столбов может быть много (около 20) поэтому нужно чтобы в квери можно было вручную байты забивать какие вытаскивать, 8000 это так navicat сдампил таблицу :)

Comment: Количество столбков будет формироватся скриптами на сервере, мне главное пример хотябы с 2 столбцами!

Comment: Ну тогда без PIVOT'ов, по-деревенски (и без группировок, по чему группировать -- не знаю):

     select sum(case LocalName when CAST(0x01000f0800ff AS binary(6)) then Value else 0 end) as param1, 
        sum(case LocalName when CAST(0x01000f0801ff AS binary(6)) then Value else 0 end) as param2 
        from RW_ReceivedData

Comment: Не коррекно работает, сумма не нужна, я убрал получилось 

     select TOP 5
 case LogicalName when CAST(0x01000F0800FF AS binary(6)) then dbo.RW_ReceivedData.Value end as param1,
 case LogicalName when CAST(0x01000F3A00FF AS binary(6)) then dbo.RW_ReceivedData.Value end as param2
     from RW_ReceivedData WHERE DeviceID = 1

но в итоге показывает только первый параметр в первой строке, далее нулл везде.

проверели запросом 

    select top 5 Value from RW_ReceivedData where DeviceID = 1 and LogicalName = CAST(0x01000F0800FF AS binary(6)) 

показывает корректно все 5 строк

Comment: И кто же такой умный Вам сказал, что сумма не нужна? Запрос должен из нескольких строк формировать одну. Для положительных чисел можно использовать функцию MAX. Если нужно несколько строк, то нужно определить группы (GROUP BY), которые будут формировать результирующую строку.

Comment: В том-то и дело, нужны значения по каждому параметру, значений может быть очень много (если я делаю сумму он мне их все сумирует и выдает 1 строкой) а нужно вывести список где в каждом столбце значения отфильтрованное по параметру (6байт)

Answer (score 2):

Возьмём предложенный мной запрос:

```
 select sum(case LogicalName when CAST(0x01000f0800ff AS binary(6)) then Value else 0 end) as param1, 
    sum(case LogicalName when CAST(0x01000f0801ff AS binary(6)) then Value else 0 end) as param2 
    from RW_ReceivedData
```

Представим, что у нас имеются две строки: одна (1) с LogicalName == 0x01000f0800ff, другая  (2) с LogicalName == 0x01000f0801ff. В результате мы получим строку из двух полей -- param1 -- сумма строк с Value строки (1) + 0, param2 -- сумма 0 + Value строки (2).

Если Вы хотите получить в результате несколько строк "развёрнутых по горизонтали", то Вы должны определить, из каких строк формируется первая строка результата, вторая и т.д.
В sql для этого служит механизм группировки (GROUP BY ...). Тогда сумма результирующих полей будет браться по одной группе. Одна строка (если такая строка есть) будет давать реальное значение, остальные будут давать 0, на сумму не влияющий. (Так же в PIVOT есть признак группировки -- перед FOR).

То есть, допустим, у нас есть какой-то признак группирования G (имя поля). И есть какой-то атрибут F, задающий, в какой столбец должно попасть значение.

[image]

Значения v1..v5 в правой (результирующей) таблице должны получаться из строк с соответствующим значением G левой таблицы (из трёх -- первая и из двух -- вторая). Наиболее простым способом является суммирование выражения

```
   case F when f1 then V else 0 end
```

Т.е. если значение должно попасть в этот столбец, то мы это значение берём, если нет -- берём 0.

Comment: Проблема только в том что мне не нужно сумировать данные. нужно получить список :/

Comment: Добавил в ответ диаграмму. Попробуйте по ней объяснить, что Вам не подходит.